# Interface importance in Prism implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Is it necessary to implement interface at module level and with viewmodel in prism application?

I am not seeing any interface which could be used with multiple class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, view models in prism do not need to implement any interface. Not even `INotifyPropertyChanged`, if you don't have any data that changes from the logic-side and not from the view.

In older versions, there was `IView` which the *views* had to implement to use the `ViewModelLocator`, but that doesn't exist anymore.

Module definitions need to implement `IModule`.

EDIT after comments:

You want to create an interface for a single class if you want to be able to replace it with another class, either in production or in test.

That being said, you don't create an interface for a class, normally, but the other way round. The interface comes first and specifies what the consumer wants to do with the implementation and then one or more classes provide the implementation for one or more interfaces each.

Example:

Given the class

```
internal class InventoryManager
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ListItems() { ... }

    public void AddItem( string item ) { ... }

    public void RemoveItem( string item ) { ... }
}
```

you don't create this interface:

```
public interface IInventoryManager
{
    IEnumerable<string> ListItems();

    void AddItem( string item );

    void RemoveItem( string item );
}
```

but rather these two:

```
public interface IItemList
{
    IEnumerable<string> ListItems();
}

public interface IItemStorage
{
    void AddItem( string item );

    void RemoveItem( string item );
}
```

because your interface's consumers will probably either want to look what's in the inventory or change it. And you want the option to implement a read-only inventory differently than a writeable one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

Comment: Yes Viewmodel will inherit viewmodelbase class which implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. And to implement module in prism we have to implement I module. My main question is if there is no more then 0ne class which can implement same interface. In that case is it good to create interface only for one class. If we are not doing same then we lose the loosely coupled concept.

Comment: I don't get it. You can have an unlimited amount of classes implementing a single interface, but you can also only have one. Most of the time, you have at least two: one in production code and one in unit tests.

Comment: Yes, I want to know.. Ii it good practice to create interface only for a single class.